# TCP Server Mono for Android Socket.bind

Tags: sockets, tcp, xamarin.android

I am trying to convert a code that can handle a TCP server in Mono for Android. It is the code from [this chat app for Windows tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16916/A-Chat-Application-Using-Asynchronous-TCP-Sockets). However, I am getting the error:

> ListenForClient Access Denied!

It is created by this part of the code:

```
try
{
    //We are using TCP sockets
    serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                              SocketType.Stream,
                              ProtocolType.Tcp);

    //Assign the any IP of the machine and listen on port number 1000
    IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 1000);

    //Bind and listen on the given address
    serverSocket.Bind(ipEndPoint);
    serverSocket.Listen(4);

    //Accept the incoming clients
    serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(OnAccept), null);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("@ ListenForClient" + ex.Message);
    Android.Util.Log.Info("ListenForClient", ex.Message);
}
```

It looks like that the `serverSocket.Bind(IPEndPoint);` is not allowed in Mono for Android.
Does anybody know a workaround or know why its not allowed?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, it was 2 problems,

1) android manifest:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

2) port 1000 is reserved!

Comment: Hi Reint Jan Hoiting, I can't get my socket server working on the simulator. I have tried your solution without success. Any pointers?